Some of the output is missing
I wrote a shiny flexdashboard file. When it's rendered on the server it only work sometimes. Sometimes output only includes the static things made in R but it's doesn't always show the output what is the result of the shiny code. Can someone explain to me what is wrong if something?
Here is web location of the output:
https://7c0ate-gunnar0bj0rn-bj0rnsson.shinyapps.io/mlabor/
Here bolow is the code of the Rmd file:
---
title: "Dæmi um vefmælaborð"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(kableExtra)

gagnagrunnur <- read_delim("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gunnarbb74/Rfiles/main/gagnagrunnur.csv", delim = ";", escape_double = FALSE, locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), trim_ws = TRUE)
gagnagrunnur$postnr <- factor(gagnagrunnur$postnr)
gagnagrunnur$sveitarfelag <- factor(gagnagrunnur$sveitarfelag)
gagnagrunnur$tegund <- factor(gagnagrunnur$tegund)
gagnagrunnur$kaupverd <- gagnagrunnur$kaupverd/1000
gagnagrunnur$fasteignamat <-gagnagrunnur$fasteignamat/1000

levels(gagnagrunnur$tegund) <- c("Annað", "Atvinnuhúsnæði", "Bílskúr/Skúr", "Fjölbýli", "Sérbýli", "Sumarhús")

listi_2sortir <- c("Fjölbýli","Sérbýli")
gagnagrunnur_2tegundir <- filter(gagnagrunnur,tegund%in%listi_2sortir)



Hf <- filter(gagnagrunnur_2tegundir,sveitarfelag =="Hafnarfjarðarkaupstaður")
Hf$sveitarfelag <- droplevels(Hf$sveitarfelag)
Hf$postnr <- droplevels(Hf$postnr)
Hf$tegund <- droplevels(Hf$tegund)




```

Column {data-width=100}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Póstnúmer

```{r}
listi_postnr <- unique(Hf$postnr)

breytulisti <- names(Hf)


selectInput(inputId = "postnr",
                      label = "Veldu póstnúmer",
                      choices = listi_postnr)

output$mynd_boxplot <- renderPlot({Hf %>% 
      filter(postnr == input$postnr) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=tegund, y=kaupverd)) +geom_boxplot()})

output$mynd_scatter <- renderPlot({Hf%>% 
      filter(postnr == input$postnr) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=einflm, y=kaupverd, color=tegund)) +geom_point() + xlab("Fermetrar")})

```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Dreifing fasteignaverðs í milljónum

```{r}

plotOutput("mynd_boxplot")
```

### Fasteignaverð í tölum (verð í milljónum)

```{r}


flokkun <- group_by(Hf,postnr,tegund)
info <- summarise(flokkun, Meðalverð = mean(kaupverd), Staðalfrávik = sd(kaupverd), Dýrast = max(kaupverd), Ódýrast=min(kaupverd))


info %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Column {data-width=300}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Samband fermetra og verðs

```{r}
plotOutput("mynd_scatter")
```

### Í hvaða hverfum eru eignirnar

```{r}
talning <- Hf %>%
group_by(postnr, tegund) %>%
summarise(tidni = n())

ggplot(talning, aes(x= postnr, y=tidni, fill = tegund)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + geom_text(data  = talning, aes(x=, y=tidni, label = tidni), position = position_stack(vjust=0.5)) + labs(x="", y="Fjöldi", title="Tegundir eftir hverfum")
```


I think the solution is as easy as the YAML - runtime: shiny should be all the way to the left (against the 'wall', in other words, not indented at all).
